# Is it allowed to use adjective clause inside the other adjective clause?

Tags: adjectives

Original problem:

> Understanding and using English Grammar 4th ed. By. B. S. Azar p. 291
>
> *Complete the sentences with your own words. Use adjective clauses.*
>
> 8. In my apartment building, there are twenty apartments, several of __________

I'd like to use "whose" to express something that possessed by **twenty apartments**. In this case I chose **people who live in those apartments**.

Then, here's my sentence:

> In my apartment building, there are twenty apartments, several of
> *whose people who live in are friends of mine.*

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is unnatural.

To use "whose" to describe what you have specified, you could say

> In my apartment building, there are twenty apartments several of whose people *living there* are friends of mine.